# does EF 4 have Audit and Logical Deletes support built in?

Tags: entity-framework

Does EF 4 have built in audit / logical delete support?  After using SubSonic and getting use to how nicely this was handled automagically I was hoping I might have the same luck with EF 4 but haven't found any documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not built in, no. You could build an audit feature fairly easily with the [tracing provider](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers). For soft deletes, you can handle `ObjectContext.SavingChanges()` to change a delete to an update and filter "deleted" records at the data service layer.